# Wildfly 10 tuning

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a JSF application hosted on Wildfly 10. For some reason when web clients are 75+ I see blank page.
Probably there is a default threat pool limit in Wildfly? Can you give some general advice how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: No, I'm still looking for some solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inspecting the memory usage of the server on this load.
You can get very useful stats using VisualVM.

If you see the server is running out of memory, solution could be as simple as 
increasing the heap memory, might as well want to tweek MetaspaceSize parameter.

One recommendation would be to use jmeter and gradually increase the load and check stats using profiling tool.
This will help you narrow down if you have some memory leaks in your application it self.